# android -java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager

Tags: android

I've got this error on my app , I don't know which activity it is , where the problem is .
this is the error log :

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:655)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:162)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:319)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302)
at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.dismiss(Spinner.java:828)
at android.widget.Spinner.onDetachedFromWindow(Spinner.java:405)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:11835)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2615)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2613)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2932)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:4343)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I find out which activity is it and what is the problem ?

thanks

Comment: why don't you accept answers to your questions!

Answer (score 1):

Probabely you are using a Context for a dialog which the Context is not available anymore.